# MS Access query for multiple NULLs

Tags: null, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create a MS Access query tied to a single table in my database that I need to only return rows where one of two fields is not empty.  Said another way, if both of the fields are empty I do not want to display that row.  Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the query design window?

Answer (score 0):

Given Columns X and Y being the ones you want to filter against:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE X IS NOT NULL and Y IS NOT NULL
```

In the Query window the equivalent would be having "is not null" on the same row for the two columns

Comment: This doesn't work as it only returns the results where both columns are populated and I want to display if either is populated.

Comment: I changed your "and" to and "or" and it works.  Thanks

Comment: "if both of the fields are empty I do not want to display that row"... I guess you meant if either field is empty...